# How to pass string variable from Java class in an Android activity to a PHP file?

Tags: java, php, mysql, get

In my Android project I have a main screen, the Java class associated with this activity holds an 'id' variable, how do I send this 'id' to a PHP so I can then run a query on my database?

Essentially what I want to do is get the 'id' variable from the Java class, then run a query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?` on the PHP file.

Comment: you can use json

Comment: Send it as string using http post or get request? or as json payload?

Comment: @frz3993 so something like $id = $_GET["id"] would get the id from the java class and place the string in php $id variable?

Comment: You can do that if you use Java `HttpURLConnection` and make a get request to the PHP script. Example :`www.example.com/index.php?id=1`.

Comment: @frz3993 I see, but it seems the id numbe is hardcoded in the link? my id variable will be changing string values constantly

Comment: You can concat the variable string value to the url. Example `String urlString = "www.example.com/index.php?id="+variableId;`. Something like that